# SwiftUI: how to use .sizeCategory to customize text size for a SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to switch on the size of the text in a SegmentedControl in SwiftUI based on .sizeCategory but it seems like the value of it isn't set in time for the `init` as its always .large whether I have my iPhone in a larger text size or normal.  How can I read whether the user is using a larger text size to be able to switch in the init of this view?

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    
       init() {
            
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
                .font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: sizeCategory > ContentSizeCategory.large ? .caption2 : .headline)
            ], for: .normal)
            
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: your code says if sizeCtegory is lesser than .large then shows text as caption2 which is smaller and if sizeCategory is smaller then show it as headline is this intentional ?

Comment: @MohmmadS that's a greater than symbol not lesser.  

Comment: I tested with print statements and if I increase the text size in the `init` it still says sizeCategory is .large, but in an `.onAppear` block it says it is .accessibilityLarge.  So the problem is the init just isn't getting the correct value of sizeCategory.

Comment: I'm afraid `size.Category` is deprecated, you should use `dynamicTypeSize` instead with its appropriate enum values. 